# ubuntu stuck on initramfs kernel panic exit code-0x00000100

Tags: ubuntu, initramfs

I have a system with ubuntu 18.04, and i edited profile file with wrong directory(and reloaded the profile with source), after few seconds all the windows has started shutting down.
on restart i get now the BusyBox 1.27.2 shell which get me to (initramfs).
tried to type "exit" and i got the error:

run-init: splash: No such file or directory

[96. some numbers] [Kernel panic - not syncing: Attempted to kill init! exitcode=0x00000100

[same..]

[same..] CPU: 7PID: 1 Comm: run-init Not tainted 4.15.0-99-generic #100-Ubuntu

and from here my hardware, and call trace of some assembly code.

how can i fix it? i can't find the profile file from here, and if i do, i don't have vi or vim or nano to edit it neither.

Comment: SO is for programming questions only, so OS support is [off-topic](/help/on-topic). You can ask on [ubuntu.se] instead.

Answer (score 2):

This is expected. When you type exit, it kills the shell. The PID1 of initramfs is a shell script called /init. When you kill the shell, the shell script has nothing left to do and exits. However, Linux does not expect the shell script to exit and so crashes.